# Congratulations to Schroeder for hitting 100k

Tags: discussion, reputation

Congratulations to @Schroeder for hitting 100k! Our 5th 100k-er

He not only manages to be the most active moderator on Sec.SE, but also has answered over 1500 questions

Well done!

Comment: Thanks Rory! And I thought I'd stop once I hit 90k since "grinding to 100k" seemed like too much like work.

Comment: I've got 40k to grind... and I rarely answer anything these days, so it's mostly grinding jam

Comment: I've wondered how my activity compares to other Stack's sites' mods. Sometimes I wonder if I'm ***too*** active...

Comment: You're only too active if it impacts your life negatively :-)

Comment: Well done, @schroeder.  You have a knack for explaining to people that they don't know what they don't know.

Comment: @mti2935 lol - I'm not sure if you meant that as a good thing or a bad thing :)

Comment: Congrats @schroeder !! I have read a lot of your answers and learnt from them!! I look forward to more contributions from you and education for the rest of us :)

Answer (score 12):

It's the third time now that I tried to write something that really encapsulates how much respect I have for you, but nothing really quite manages.

As such, I'll keep myself short:

Thank you for everything you've done for Security.SE. Without you, the site would definitely look a lot different, and not for the better. I've learned a lot from you in my time here, and I hope I will continue to learn just as much.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind words. It helps to get this kind of feedback every once in a while since I mostly get negative feedback from upset users. I am grateful that my efforts are useful, even if imperfect.

Comment: @schroeder Then let it be known that your effort doesn't go unnoticed and is highly appreciated.

Comment: @schroeder you are awesome but sometimes people think you are slightly rude because you are always on topic. Well done we all like you and learnt a lot from you.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations, schroeder!

I'm new around here, but I noticed very quickly that you're extremely active in moderating, but still answer a lot of questions. Which I find quite impressive. On some sites (Stack Overflow), the moderators seem to be too busy moderating to answer much anymore. But I see you taking the time to answer and make sure that even people with very little infosec knowledge understand what you're saying.

Which brings the question...

How on earth do you have the time to do all that and still have a job in real-life???

Comment: I ask myself this question, too! I think the secret is to have been on the site for so long that I can remember so many core questions that it's easy to spot a duplicate, and then to know where the gaps are in existing answers. So, it's easy to quickly come up with answers. In other words: a lot of auto-pilot...  Plus it helps that my job consists of so many meetings, that I am on here while people try to convince me that "patching is hard, so I'd rather not do it ..."

Answer (score 9):

A small sample of some of the great answers:

- [Possibly the highest reputation per word on the site?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162021/what-is-the-purpose-of-confirming-old-password-to-create-a-new-password/162023#162023)
- [A clown who claims he was at the last company party.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197732/roles-to-play-when-tailgaiting-into-a-residential-building/197733#197733)
- [Sometimes controversial, but always well reasoned.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/192536/98538)
- Not to mention the 158 answers that got zero upvote, but just looking at a small sample will show that they are full of helpful nuggets.

Thanks and congratulations! :-)

Comment: What a fascinating collection of my posts. If someone knew nothing else about me but what was in those 3 posts, what conclusions would they come to?? Thanks for the trip down memory lane! And gosh, sorting my answers by reverse vote count is a little depressing ...

Comment: Hehe, didn't mean to depress you. :-) My point is that there are so many contributions that are not even measured in rep that still counts for building the comunity.